# MySQL subquery error not "propagated" to outer query

Tags: mysql, subquery

I have been trying to track down erroneous behaviour in existing MySQL (5.7, Linux) code.  I am astounded/puzzled/unhappy at the behaviour I have discovered *when a subquery returns an error*:

```
SELECT * FROM charges WHERE ChargeID IN
    (SELECT ChargeID FROM history WHERE BatchID = 3500);
```

The above query is returning 0 rows.  Investigating further, the subquery:

```
SELECT ChargeID FROM history WHERE BatchID = 3500
```

turns out to be raising error (which is *correct*):

```
Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'ChargeID' in 'field list'
```

I had no idea that a subquery was returning an error.  But the outer query simply returns 0 rows, "successfully".

Here is what I see in MySQL Workbench.  Note how the output successfully reports returning 0 rows for the first query while producing an error for the second query (which is the subquery):

```
SELECT * FROM charges WHERE ChargeID IN
  (SELECT ChargeID FROM history WHERE BatchID = 3500);

SELECT ChargeID FROM history WHERE BatchID = 3500;


10:18:02    SELECT * FROM charges WHERE ChargeID IN   (SELECT ChargeID FROM history WHERE BatchID = 3500) LIMIT 0, 1000 0 row(s) returned   0.0017 sec / 0.0000091 sec
10:18:02    SELECT ChargeID FROM history WHERE BatchID = 3500 LIMIT 0, 1000 Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'ChargeID' in 'field list' 0.00020 sec
```

Why does MySQL not return an error for the outer query?  (I'd also appreciate a documentation reference explaining this behaviour?)  How do I make it return an error in such a case?  As it stands, for all I know there may be many occurrences in existing code with such an erroneous subquery without my being aware of any of them...

Comment: I am testing this in MySQL Workbench.  I will paste some proof now....

Comment: @fancyPants I expect to find a response as to whether it's correct or not, and/or whether there's something I can do about it in the query.  It's happening in our code too, not just in WB.  I do not expect an unhelpful "What do you expect from posting this here?".

Comment: I tested on MariaDB 10, but it gives error as expected. Most probably the issue is related to your client.

Comment: By the way, what happens if you put `EXPLAIN` in front of your query?

Comment: I am playing in WB.  What seems to be the cause --- which I am *just* beginning to twig is --- the column name in the outer query `ChargeID` *must be* the same name (`ChargeID`, which *does* exist there) as referenced as a column in the sub-query (which does *not* exists there).  Are you people testing with that?  I am guessing this is the problem area: somehow in the double-query the `ChargeID` in the subquery is trying to be the column in the outer query...!!

Comment: My apologies, I could have known the answer if I had read your question more carefully and put more brainpower into it. That makes my comment even more inappropriate.

Comment: @fancypants It is much appreciated that you have chosen to revisit this question and posted your latest comment.  Now I wish you all the best :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer my own question, now that I have been inspired to play around a bit.

Firstly, note that, contrary to comments, it does not seem to be a client issue.  Whether it is a bug/feature/intended in MySQL I do not know.  But it is certainly a worrying behaviour to try to detect.

First, the following slightly altered code *does* correctly return an error:

```
SELECT * FROM charges WHERE ChargeID IN
    (SELECT zzzChargeID FROM history WHERE BatchID = 3500);
```

Here I have changed the column name in the subquery to `zzzChargeID`, which is *not* the same as the `ChargeID` which does exist as a column in the outer table.  Now there is "ambiguity", and the whole query returns an error.

The problem arises when: the subquery references by name a column which *does* exist in the outer query's table but does *not* exist in the subquery:

```
SELECT * FROM charges WHERE ChargeID IN
    (SELECT ChargeID FROM history WHERE BatchID = 3500);
```

Here the subquery tries to access a column, named `ChargeID`, which does not exist in its table but does exist in the outer table.  *MySQL is taking the inner reference to `ChargeID` as referring to the `ChargeID` column of the outer table*, which is not at all as intended!

Then the result depends on whether the `WHERE` clauses of the inner query finds *any* matching row in its table:

- if it *does* (there is a row with `BatchID = 3500`) then the outer
  query returns *all rows* from its `charges` table;
- if it does *not*
  (there is *no* row with `BatchID = 3500`) then the outer query
  returns *0 rows* from its `charges` table.

The upshot thus is: given this behaviour, one should *never* dare write a query like:

```
SELECT col1, ... FROM table1 WHERE col1 IN
    (SELECT col1 FROM table2 ...)
```

The `col1` in the subquery is not qualified with its table name.  To be sure that one does not accidentally pick a column name which does not exist in the subquery's table but does exist in the outer table, one *must* qualify with:

```
SELECT col1, ... FROM table1 WHERE col1 IN
    (SELECT table2.col1 FROM table2 ...)
```

This is very worrying, as potentially the existing code base could be full of such unqualified columns in subqueries references, which are not generating errors but are silently producing undesired results.

If anyone knows whether there is a better solution than changing every single subquery's code accordingly I should be most grateful to hear it.